# Large numbers/integers in dot notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integer, notation

Any handy method to have for instance the number 1000000 become 1.000.000 and 10000 become 10.000 etc? I'm dealing with integers so comma's are not a necessity to include (but would be handy though, like 10.000,53).

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you mean writing the number in code, you can use underscores like `1_000_000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `number_with_delimiter` [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_delimiter).

This is assuming that you're using Ruby on Rails, not just Ruby. `number_with_delimiter` is a Rails helper method that isn't available in Ruby, unless you coded it yourself.